# Creating an importable webpack library into Vite

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules, vite

I've stumbled upon an issue with a library that I'm trying to integrate into my project. I've decided to fork it to provide the internal components as exports of the library.

For the consuming project I'm using Vite, while the forked project uses webpack.
I've read a bit about library creation in webpack here
https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/

I've also create a minimal example via vite.

This is my import statement in a vite react app:

```
import "webpack-numbers";
```

This works correctly from the webpack docs:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="./dist/webpack-numbers.js"></script>
    <script>
        console.log(webpackNumbers.wordToNum('Five'));
        console.log(window.webpackNumbers.wordToNum('Five'));
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The webpack config

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'webpack-numbers.js',
        globalObject: 'this',
        library: {
            name: 'webpackNumbers',
            type: 'umd',

        },
    },
};
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: n is undefined
    <anonymous> http://localhost:5174/@fs/home/blewandowski/repositories/personal/webpack-numbers/dist/webpack-numbers.js?t=1672834535153:2
    <anonymous> http://localhost:5174/@fs/home/blewandowski/repositories/personal/webpack-numbers/dist/webpack-numbers.js?t=1672834535153:2
```

How does one go about consuming these exports in a vite react app?

Comment: Have you tried a different `type` like `module` or `commonjs2`?

Comment: module worked for me in my minimal example, not so much in the app I'm developing, I'll do more digging